# Why doesn't the taskbar show the app button when a Modal Dialog is in the timer? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd want to show a modal dialog while executing inside the `OnTimer()` function.

Like the example below:

```
void OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer)
{
    if(timer == 1){

        ...

        MainFrame.DoModal();

        ...
    }
    return;
}
```

Although it shows the dialog successfully, but the taskbar doesn't show the app button.

Like the image below:

[image: It shows the dialog successfully, but there isn't any app button on the taskbar]

What's the reason? How to solve this problem?

Below is the complete code: (First 5 seconds it shows the normal modal dialog, which has the app button on the taskbar. After, it shows the modal dialog in the timer, which has no app button on the taskbar)

```
#include <afxwin.h> 
#include "resource.h"

class CMainDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CMainDlg(CWnd *wnd = NULL):CDialog(IDD_DIALOG2, wnd){}
    CString title;

    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

        return TRUE;
    }
};

class CSpashDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CSpashDlg(CWnd *wnd = NULL):CDialog(IDD_DIALOG1, wnd){}
    CMainDlg MainFrame;

    BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

        SetTimer(1, 5000, 0);

        return TRUE;
    }

    void OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer)
    {
        if(timer == 1){
            KillTimer(timer);
            PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, IDCANCEL);

            MainFrame.DoModal();

            DestroyWindow();
        }
        return;
    }
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSpashDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();

        CSpashDlg Frame;
        Frame.DoModal();

        return true;
    }
} a_app;
```

Comment: This looks to be a decade old Windows bug. Poke around. There is no exact recipe here.

Comment: I forgot to say that the Windows XP image above is just a demonstration. Actually, not only in Windows XP but also in Windows 10 has the same problem. The OS of my computer is Windows 10, so I know this problem not only happens in Windows XP.

Comment: I remember this problem starting at least from Win95. If you open some popup dialog from Windows explorer or Control Panel and then minimize maximize it several times or overlap with other windows, there is a certain chance that it will disappear both from desktop and the taskbar.

Comment: Try to post a WM_COMMAND message from the handler of the timer message and then show your popup from there. This may help.

Comment: It only does that in WinXP. I think  you are mistaken about Windows 10. It works as expected in Win10, I just tried it.